# VBA Subtraction using Index ranges produces Run time error 13

Tags: excel, vba

I have included a small snippet of code which, via debugging, I noticed generates a type mismatch (error 13) and i do not understand why:

```
Sub Subtract()
  Dim Index, Lastrow As Integer

  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = Sheet1

  With ws
    Lastrow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For Index = 2 To Lastrow
        ws.Range("F" & Index).Value = ws.Range("E" & Index).Value - ws.Range("E" & Index - 1).Value
    Next Index
  End With
End Sub
```

I am certain that the problem is this bit of code:

ws.Range("E" & Index - 1).Value

So I' tried a few things, one of them being to assign **Index** to a variable like so:

```
a = Index - 1
```

and then substituted **a** into the forumla like so

```
ws.Range("F" & Index).Value = ws.Range("E" & Index).Value - ws.Range("E" & a).Value
```

But i still got the same error. I think I understand now that i am not supposed to be doing maths in that range function so my question is this...

How do i subtract the values of two indexed cells ? For Example:

```
ColE  ColF
  20   0
  20   0
  30   10
  30   0
  40   10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start your Index loop at 3, so you don't try to substract "ColE" from 20.